# Debian, issue with ImageTk: "cannot import 'ImageTk' from 'PIL' "

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

My imports:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os
```

My code:

```
image = Image.open("path/download.bmp")
root = tk.Tk()
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
```

I tried all apt-get installation commands that I've found and nothing works. Please, help.
When I run commands like `sudo apt-get install python3-pil.imagetk`, I get

```
Package python3-pil.imagetk is not available, but is referred to by another package.

 ... Package 'python3-pil.imagetk' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Have you named your script `PIL.py`, by any chance?  That would get picked up by the `import` instead of the actual module.

Comment: @jasonharper, nope I named it 'gettingStarted.py' .

Comment: @alais1 Try `pip3 install Pillow`

Answer (score 0):

So... I didn't find a solution but I ended up just getting rid of ImageTk class, writing something as simple as

```
photo = PhotoImage(file="path/download.gif")
```

This solution also required me converting the .bmp to .gif .